# Spring , React Oauth2.0 google login

Tags: reactjs, spring, security

I'm asking because I don't know well yet. Please give me a hint if there is any other way. Bow..

<1>I'm going to Google login React + Spring oauth2.0 but should I secure Spring and hand over the access token to React address + queryString directly to the redirect path, create the middle page in React, save it, and look up the membership information with that?

<2> Or is it right to just make a button with the @react-oauth/google library on the Rest Controller, receive the Google social token that you received after successfully logging in with client_id from the Spring Rest Controller, and then use Google verify to issue the membership + token directly from the service group and hand over the user information to json?.. Then, the settings related to the Spring APi permission will be..

The jwt token authentication method is being used without the session.

I'm sorry I didn't explain it well..

Masters, please.

<1> redirect + farm or spring security oauth success Handler send Redirect

React Google login button = server address/oauth2/authorization/google

<2> Spring Rest Controller Novel Temporary Token (with Spring Oauth SuccessHandler x)

React Google login button = @react-auth/google client_id enabled

Answer (score 0):

Google access tokens audience is Google. Understand that you can't easily / efficiently use it for your own resource servers. You'll have to use an Authorization server of your own. Almost any OpenID Provider supports Google as identy provider (Keycloak, Auth0, Amazon Cognito, spring-authorization-server and many others)

Additionaly, [single-page applications aren't reliable OAuth2 clients](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) (apps running on end-user devices are "public" clients when we should be using only "confidential" clients). Unless you are using a server-side OAuth2 client library (like next.js has), you should introduce a BFF configured as an OAuth2 confidential client and something to bridge between session and token security. For instance, spring-cloud-gateway with `oauth2Login()` and `TokenRelay`. I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).